# User Input To End Close Console

Tags: c++, dev-c++

I  have a do while loop to keep cycling through my int main(). I did this by creating a bool called keepGoing. Now im stuck incorporating a press "q" or type "exit" to end program.

Ive tried stuff like if (exitCon == 'quit') then exit program. But everything i try keeps displaying error messages.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>



using namespace std; 

//function prototypes 
double DoubleInput(string strQuestion); 
double GradePoint(double &p);


int main() 
{
    const string PCENT = "%";
    bool keepGoing = true;

    cout << "===================================================================" << endl;
    cout << "                         GPA CALCULATOOR                           " << endl;
    cout << "===================================================================" << endl;

    do{
        double input = DoubleInput("\nPlease enter your numeric grade percentage: ");

        double g = GradePoint(input);


        cout << "You entered a grade of " << input << PCENT << endl; 
        cout << input << PCENT << " is equal to " << g << " grade points" << endl;

      }while(keepGoing);   
}
```

}

this is my function for getting input by the way

```
double DoubleInput(string strQuestion)
    {

        double doubleHolder;

        cout << strQuestion;
        cin >> doubleHolder;


        while(cin.fail())
        {

            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
            cout << "No non-numeric inputs. Please try again!" << endl << endl;
            cout << strQuestion;
            cin >> doubleHolder;
        }


        cout << endl;
        return doubleHolder;
    }
```

Comment: Please post the implementation of `DoubleInput`.

Comment: yes i have added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DoubleInput` has two responsibilities:

1. To read a `double`.
2. To indicate whether the user chose to enter the exit code.

The interface of the function needs to be changed to provide both.

One way to do that will be to use [`std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional), if you have access to C++17.

```
std::optional<double> DoubleInput(string strQuestion);
```

If you don't have the option of using C++17, you can use a poor man's version of `std::optional` by using:

```
std::pair<bool, double> DoubleInput(string strQuestion);
```

with the understanding that the `.first` of the returned object will be set to `true` if the input is valid and `false` if the input is invalid and/or the user chose to enter the exit code.

```
std::pair<bool, double> DoubleInput(string strQuestion)
{
   std::string input;
   double num;

   cout << strQuestion;

   // Read the input to a string.
   while( cin >> input )
   {
      // Check the input agains the exit codes.
      if ( input == "exit" || input == "q")
      {
         return std::make_pair(false, 0.0);
      }

      // Try to extract a number from the input string
      // by using istringstream.
      std::istringstream str(input);
      if ( str >> num )
      {
         return std::make_pair(true, num);
      }

      // If there is an error, try again.
      cin.clear();
      cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
      cout << "Invalid input. Please try again!" << endl << endl;
      cout << strQuestion;
   }

   // If there is nothing left in cin, we come here.
   return std::make_pair(false, 0.0);
}
```

Here's how to use it:

```
do
{
   std::pair<bool, double> input = DoubleInput("\nPlease enter your numeric grade percentage: ");
   if ( input.first == false )
   {
      break;
   }

   double g = GradePoint(input.second);

   cout << "You entered a grade of " << input.second << PCENT << endl; 
   cout << input << PCENT << " is equal to " << g << " grade points" << endl;

} while(true);
```

Comment: hey im having an error with my line 
cout << "You entered a grade of" << userInput << PCENT;

it displays no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream {aka std::basic_ostream}' and 'Point')

Comment: @MichaelMusk, that should have been `input.second`. It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to toggle the value of the boolean variable keepGoing to exit the loop. There is no other deterministic way to handle this scenario. So you have to receive the input within while loop and check is it 'q' or 'exit' and reset the variable keepGoing to false.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably reading the input in `DoubleInput`, now you have two options:

1 Not using that function and instead doing something like:

```
string str;
getline(cin, str);
if(str == "q" || str == "quit")
  keepGoing = true;
else input = stod(str);
```

2 Using the function but returning a double with a value that you pre-defined as being the value that means the user wants to quit and then check for it:

```
double input = DoubleInput(msg);
if(input == EXIT)
  keepGoing = true;
else doStuff();
```

Comment: It was what I was expecting. What I said should solve your needs anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `DoubleInput` only has the responsibility to collect a valid input i.e. in this case a positive non-zero `double` value, you can implement something like this. I called it `getDoubleInput` because I have this weird hang-up about naming functions with capital letters. You should also always pass strings as references, and constant if you're not modifying them.

```
double getDoubleInput(const std::string& prompt)
{
    double input(0.0);
    do
    {
        std::cout << prompt;
        while (!(std::cin >> input))
        {
            std::cout << "Please enter a positive number: ";
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(1024, '\n');
        }
    }
    while (input <= 0.0);

    return input;
}
```